# Excluding stuff from a windows command line "for xxx in (*.exe)"

Tags: loops, batch-file, command-line

Sorry for the unclear title, it's hard to describe my problem in few words.
So, I have the following windows command line running periodicaly

```
for /r %%i in (Vali*.dll,Vali.*.exe) do stuff
```

It does browse a folder looking for dll and exe beginning by Vali. Now the problem is I need to exclude the Valitest.
Is there a syntax to exclude something from the filter?

Thank you.

Edit : I would like a result looking like

```
for /r %%i in (Vali*.dll,Vali.*.exe, - Valitest*) do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why no-one has answered you, but it should work like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %%I IN (Vali*.dll,Vali.*.exe) DO (
   (ECHO %%I | FINDSTR /I "TEST" > NUL) || (
     ECHO %%I
   )
)
```

The loop is just the same as yours, except as I find each file, I test whether it contains the word "TEST", or "test" (that is the `/I` on `FINDSTR` to make it *insensitive* to case) and if that word is not present, I do the innermost chunk of code.